# Get details of a Git Commit using only the SHA-1 hash through the GitHub REST API or GraphQL API v4

Tags: git, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Is it possible to get details of a Git Commit using only the SHA-1 hash (without knowing the repository name and the respective branch) using the GitHub REST API or GraphQL API v4?

As per [specification](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit) of GitHub's REST API, it isn't possible. Currently, I am using the GitHub GraphQL API and I have not been successful in achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

You can search commit with a specific sha using [Search commit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits) :

```bash
curl "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=6302aad48c5cb56c9f9c3fb7aa73d2f1f2f10540" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview"
```